# JAX-RS inject the value of URI parameter

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs, postman

I am trying to get the user by id with the following method:

```
@Path("/v1/user/")
public class UserRestService extends BaseRestWebService {

        @GET
        @Path("/customers/{id}")  
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        public Catalog getCustomerById(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathParam("id") String userId){

            IlsCustomer customer = getUserService().getUserById(IlsCustomer.class, Long.parseLong(userId));


            Catalog catalog = new Catalog();


            catalog.add(customer);
            return catalog;
        }


}
```

I am using Postman and in postman when I type: `https://localhost:8181/iPCP/restServices/v1/user/customers/6560`
I am getting error :

```
The page cannot be found (404)
You tried to access a page that does not exist. Please check the entered URL.
```

But if I type URL: `https://localhost:8181/iPCP/restServices/v1/user/customers`
the response is:  `{}`

Comment: What happens if the customer doesn't exist?

Comment: What is Catalog? Usually your return type should be Response such that you can define the status. E.g.
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(catalog).build();

Comment: Ok, thank I will try, can you provide some example? That thinks can help me

Comment: show your web.xml